# Throwing general exception in Java

Tags: java, error-handling

This is for an online tutorial in throwing exceptions

I am trying to do something like this:

```
int power(int n, int p){
        try
        {
            return (int)Math.pow(n,p);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("n and p should be non-negative");
        }
    }
```

But I get the error

> error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Exception` is a checked exception, which means that if a method wants to throw it, it must declare it in a `throws` clause.

```
int power(int n, int p) throws Exception {
    try
    {
        return (int)Math.pow(n,p);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("n and p should be non-negative");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I understand now, but why does it need to be thrown in the function header? better question i think is why is checked exception?

Comment: @PawelK because `Exception` and all of it's children **must** be declared as they are **checked** `Exception`s. Children of `RuntimeException` are **unchecked** and therefore do not need to be declared. Them's the rules.

Comment: I would not have expected such a rule, feels like should possible to throw exception always anywhere

Comment: It is a checked exception as opposed to a runtime exception which means you must declare the exception is throw in the method signature. This warns any callers of the method to expect an exception so they can act accordingly.

Comment: @PawelK what makes you feel that way? Surely it makes sense to have to inform calling code of possible error conditions they might encounter, no?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Perhaps, but then why unchecked exceptions exist?

Comment: @PawelK The Java language requires you to handle (i.e. catch) any checked exception, and if you choose not to handle it, you must say so explicitly in the method's signature (using a throws clause), so that the callers of your method will know they have to handle this exception. Any sub-class of Exception (including Exception, not including RuntimeException and its sub-classes) is a checked exception.

Comment: @PawelK for error conditions that cannot be corrected by calling code. For example `FileNotFoundException` is checked - the caller might want to create the file or otherwise fix the issue. `NullPointerException` is unchecked - there is no way to deal with dereferencing a `null` reference.

Comment: What if you wish to throw multiple types of exceptions? "n is negative" "p should be even" "n did not call p back after their date yesterday" etc

Comment: @PawelK either create a parent `MathematicsException extends Exception` and declare that your method throws it. Then create whatever subclasses you want - this is how, for example, the [Java 8 NIO.2 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) works; it declares `IOException` and throws numerous subclasses. Or delcare each exception, as in the [Java reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html); this approach can lead to messy `try..catch` blocks however.

Comment: @BoristheSpider So UNchecked exceptions are sort of like unforeseen bugs in the program that are hard to deal with once encountered?

Comment: @PawelK that's the idea. Exceptions that cannot be recovered from should be unchecked. Everything else should be checked. Exceptions should have a sensible class hierarchy, just like your object classes.